# Accessing the route's transition animation from a widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two pages, both with their own Scaffold and a slightly different AppBar. I use `Navigator.push` to switch between them.

The second page is a popup which overlays the first page by having a transparent Scaffold with body of about 50% screen height. Here's how it looks:

[image: The second page]

In the first page, the red curtain ends just below the AppBar. When you open the second page, the curtain animates down to the screenshot above. I achieved this by starting the down animation in `initState` of the second screen.

Now, I want the opposite animation of the curtain rolling back up when you leave the second page. How would I do that? Is there a way to animate widgets (not just fade/slide whole pages) when you enter/leave the page?

Can I access the `Route`'s transition animation (the same one that is passed to `Route.buildTransitions`) and use it to animate widgets inside the page itself?